# My favicon is not appearing no matter what I try

Tags: html, favicon

I know this feels like an age-old question but I cannot for the life of me seem to get this thing to work! I've cleared all caches & history on both Safari and Chrome but the image still won't load. I'm aware there are other posts here asking the same question but I've done every single thing those posts say, and nothing's worked!

I used https://favicon.io to generate the favicon and all the images are sat in the root directory folder.

Here's the code for the favicon, sat within the head area:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

Can anyone think why the favicon still isn't working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `link rel` should be `"shortcut icon"`.

Comment: you put the element in the head tag right? and try rename the image and make sure the path is correct `<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.png">`